# How to redirect if controller wasn't found? (cakephp)

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

This is my routes file. How can I redirect to array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home') if controller wasn't found?

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
Router::connect('/login', array("controller"=>"user","action"=>"login"));
Router::connect('/settings', array("controller"=>"user","action"=>"settings"));
Router::connect('/logout', array("controller"=>"user","action"=>"logout"));
Router::connect('/video', array("controller"=>"video","action"=>"index"));
Router::connect('/video/page/*', array("controller"=>"video","action"=>"page"));
Router::connect('/video/*', array("controller"=>"video","action"=>"view")); 
Router::connect('/upcoming', array("controller"=>"user","action"=>"upcoming"));
```

Comment: When I go to this page. http://example.com/cakephp/controller_that_doesnt_exists

Comment: Please look for my reply in similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108382/cakephp-redirecting-all-404-errors-to-the-homepage/10669893#10669893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Create an `app_error.php` file in your /app directory, (just the way you would for `app_model.php` or `app_controller.php`)

Once that is done, put in the following:

```
<?php
class AppError extends ErrorHandler {


    function missingController($params) {
        extract($params, EXTR_OVERWRITE);

        $this->controller->redirect('/');
    }    


}
```

Now, this should solve your problem. If you need to invoke components and beforeFilters/Renders, you can call those from the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom Exception handler that will redirect the user back ot the homepage. See the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#create-your-own-exception-handler-with-exception-handler) on this topic.

Probably something like this (untested, but just to give you an idea where to go from here):

```
class AppErrorHandler {
    public static function handleException($error) {
        if ($error instanceof MissingControllerException) {
            // Redirect home, $this->redirect will probably not work,
            // since the Error Handler doesn't extend the AppController.
            header('Location: /');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745968/cakephp-how-would-i-route-all-missing-controller-action-calls-to-a-single-gene)  explained neatly and working great>Hope this will help you.

OR

Go **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108382/cakephp-redirecting-all-404-errors-to-the-homepage)**